# Does Set.remove may return false if element exists?

Tags: java

Consider the following example:

```
public Optional<User> getUser(Integer id) {
    for(User user : usersSet) {
        if(user.getId().equals(id)) return Optional.of(user);
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}

public void deleteUser(Integer id) {
    User user = getUser(id).orElseThrow(new RuntimeException("User not found"));
    boolean result = usersSet.remove(user);
}
```

Is there any case in which the result is false?

I ask because I don´t know if it´s necessary to check the result of the `remove` method of an HashSet.

Comment: As an aside, if you are using `Optional` anyway, you can do `users.stream().filter(u -> u.getId().equals(id)).findFirst();`

Comment: Thanks for the advice :).

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no way that you can get a false if the element exist.

If you look at the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#remove(java.lang.Object)), it's clearly mentioned.

> true if this set contained the specified element

Comment: If, despite this, you get `false` even though the element appears to exist, the likely culprit is incorrectly synchronised multi-threaded application code.

Comment: But I was thinking that maybe when another thread will remove this object, then result will be false. Is it make sense?

Comment: @DamianU You never mentioned about your multi threaded environment. Huh ? Yes it is possible, if you bombard this code with different threads.

Comment: @DamianU If your code is correctly synchronised, this can't happen even in a multi-threaded environment. If however you left data races in your code, all bets are off.

Comment: @biziclop Ok, should I never check the result of remove method and for example throws exception if result is false? I just should synchronise my code, right?

Answer (score 2):

`usersSet` is probably a `java.util.Set` instance.
`Set` relies on `equals()` method for add/removal operations. 
So `boolean result = usersSet.remove(user);` will return `true` only if `equals()` of  `User` class is overrided by using the same criteria as the `getUser()` method.
 For example to simplify  : `return user.getId().equals(id);`

Answer (score 1):

YES.

**In your case result can be false** because your `users` object and userSet both are different. Moreover it depends on the way you have implemented `equal()` method for `User` class